# Display single item price html below product title in checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, price

From [Display on sale cart item formatted prices range in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66407742/display-on-sale-cart-item-formatted-prices-range-in-woocommerce/66408804#66408804) answer to my previous question, I was able to display on sale cart item formatted prices.

Unfortunately I was not able to use the product title filter to add the single product price below the product title in the checkout page. The first image shows what i try to achieve - the second how it looks like right now.

1. My cart page already shows the price below the title:
   [image]
2. My checkout page should show the price too:
   [image]

Any idea how to add the single product price html below the product title in the checkout page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [your previous question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66407742/display-on-sale-cart-item-formatted-prices-range-in-woocommerce/66408804#66408804), simply use also the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'filter_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3 );
function filter_checkout_cart_item_quantity( $item_quantity, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    return $cart_item['data']->get_price_html() . ' ' . $item_quantity;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thx for your help. The $item_quantity returns a x before the quantity. i try to remove it - should i use str_replace for example or any easier way?

Comment: @evavienna Simply replace `$item_quantity` with `$cart_item['quantity']` or with `<strong class="product-quantity">' . $cart_item['quantity'] . '</strong>'`…