# I want to show the subtotal strike out with Total Regular Price and Total Sales price. and also takes discount coupon

Tags: woocommerce, subtotal

sir,
i read one article in
[Display on sale cart item formatted prices range in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66407742/display-on-sale-cart-item-formatted-prices-range-in-woocommerce)  and solution given by LoicTheAztec
for

[Display on sale cart item formatted prices range in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66407742/display-on-sale-cart-item-formatted-prices-range-in-woocommerce)

I used the code given by you is shown below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'filter_cart_item_price', 10, 3 );
function filter_cart_item_price( $price_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( $cart_item['data']->is_on_sale() ) {
        return $cart_item['data']->get_price_html();
    }
    return $price_html;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'filter_cart_item_subtotal', 10, 3 );
function filter_cart_item_subtotal( $subtotal_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    $product    = $cart_item['data'];
    $quantity   = $cart_item['quantity'];
    $tax_string = '';

    if ( $product->is_taxable() ) {
        if ( WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
            $regular_price = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product, array( 'qty' => $quantity, 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
            $active_price  = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product, array( 'qty' => $quantity ) );

            if ( ! wc_prices_include_tax() && WC()->cart->get_subtotal_tax() > 0 ) {
                $tax_string = ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->inc_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        } else {
            $regular_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product, array( 'qty' => $quantity, 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
            $row_price     = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product, array( 'qty' => $quantity ) );

            if ( wc_prices_include_tax() && WC()->cart->get_subtotal_tax() > 0 ) {
                $tax_string = ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        }
    } else {
        $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price() * $quantity;
        $active_price  = $product->get_price() * $quantity;
    }

    if( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        return wc_format_sale_price( $regular_price, $active_price ) . $product->get_price_suffix() . $tax_string;
    }

    return $subtotal_html;
}
```

The above code strikes the Regular price and shows the Sale price but i need that
it should also show in Total item Regular Price striked and show Sale Price in subtotal also.
Also if any other discount is applied ( like Coupon ), Then the above Subtotal should take account of that also.
I need help , I am not a coder

The above code strikes the Regular price and shows the Sale price but i need that it should also show in Total item Regular Price striked and show Sale Price in subtotal also. Also if any other discount is applied ( like Coupon ), Then the above Subtotal should take account of that also. I need help , I am not a coder